# How can I choose between "-se" and "-ce" for the spelling of the word ending pronounced /s/

Tags: spelling, transatlantic-differences

How can I choose between "-se" and "-ce" for the spelling
of the word ending pronounced /s/. For example, both "sense" and "science" have the ending pronounced /s/.

Comment: I would never try to get spelling from pronunciation in English, that way madness lies.

Comment: You simply learn it by rote (by heart) or use a spell checker.  There is no rule that says one should be used or the other.  The different spelling comes due to the differences in how (or from what other word) the words formed.

Comment: ...not to mention the differences in spelling of some words in AmE and BrE (like "license" vs "licence").

Comment: And if you ask yourself *why* pronounciation and spelling are, hm, connected rather "loosely": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghoti

Comment: http://www.englishpractice.com/vocabulary/words-ce-se/

Comment: Rule: Generally, the verb form will be spelled with the “s” and the noun with the “c.”

Comment: @Yury how about "defensible", "defensibly"? To me, it is hard to look the word as "defen**c**ible"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not very many patterns that would help in most cases.  Small patterns exist but you are better off simply memorizing the spelling of common *-ce* and *-se* words.

For example - the *c* in *-ace* or *-ice* at the end of words is almost always pronounced /s/, whereas the *s* in *-ase* or *-ise* would be usually pronounced /z/.  So use *-ce* in that situation.

There are far fewer words that [end in *-ense*](http://www.wordfind.com/ends-with/ense/) than [*-ence*](http://www.wordfind.com/ends-with/ence/), and likewise less that end in *-se* with s pronounced /s/, rather than *-ce*.  So if you have to hazard a guess, go with *-ce*.

Comment: I'm surprised you don't also mention the difference between American and British English. For example, one would use "defense" in AmE and "defence" in BrE. So depending on context, someone learning the language might see both spellings. Both are correct in their respective contexts and equally understood.

Comment: And, unfortunately, AmE is rather inconsistent with which letter it uses: *defense* and *practice*, for example. BrE more consistently uses *-ce* for noun forms and *-se* for verb forms; AmE only uses one spelling or the other unless the pronunciation is different: *advise*, *advice*, *prophesy*, *prophecy*.

Comment: English orthography is a mess. Use spell-checkers (but not auto-corrupt if you can avoid it).

Comment: Is it true Americans use "defen-se" instead of "defen-ce"? N gram is showing certainly "defence" is decreasing in America...but when considering words such as defensible, defensibly, it looks like to me personally to use "defen-se" is more suitable..

Comment: >There are far fewer words that end in -ense than -ence, Really? How about such as dense, pretense, tense......

Comment: @KentaroTomono did you look at the links in my answer?

Comment: There are tons of words ending with se [link](https://www.morewords.com/ends-with/se/)